# « Le point d’avancement », « le degré d’avancement » « le niveau d’avancement » ou « où en sont »?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Est-ce que tu pourrais me montrer

…le point d’avancement des rénovations ?

…le degré d’avancement des rénovations ?

…le niveau d’avancement des rénovations ?

…où en sont les rénovations ?

Serait-il préférable de repenser la phrase et de recourir à des termes différents?

Comment: Thérèse, I apologize, I didn't notice your "où en sont"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Le **degré** d'avancement des rénovations* (ou mieux *des travaux de rénovation*) est de loin le plus idiomatique, le *niveau d'avancement* est aussi possible, mais bien plus rare.

*Le point d'avancement* fait plutôt penser à une réunion et il faudrait alors changer de verbe car on ne montre pas un point d'avancement, on le fait : *Est-ce que tu pourrais me faire un point sur l'avancement des rénovations.*

*[...] me montrer où en sont les rénovations* : rien à signaler :-)